# Trouble adding horizontal scroll on dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying the following in Javascript:

```
if (parseInt($('#' + tableName + 'Table').width()) > parseInt($('#' + tableName + 'Table').parent().width())) {
                    console.log("Here");
                    $('#' + tableName + 'Table').css('overflow-x', 'scroll');
                }
```

And it's logging to the console but there is no horizontal scroll bar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$('#' + tableName + 'Table').css('overflow-x', 'scroll');
```

To

```
$('#' + tableName + 'Table').parent().css('overflow-x', 'scroll');
```

The parent element is the one that needs the `overflow-x` property.

Also you don't need javascript for this functionality. You can just set `overflow-x: auto;` to the parent element, and it will add a scrollbar automatically if its contents are too wide.

Comment: Thanks, perfect - I wouldn't have guessed that.  But now that I think about it, that makes exact sense.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your jquery selector is wrong. You could have easily logged `$('#' + tableName + 'Table')` or stepped through your code with a debugger to see that this element did not exist or was not the correct element. Your next step would be to figure out the appropriate selector. In this case you need to target the parent of `$('#' + tableName + 'Table')`